# How to enable a row with values on a click of a(add) button

Tags: html, angular, angular6

In ticket booking apps we do have an option to add multiple persons, In the same way i should give an option for the user to add his availability time slot... where he clicks Add New button to add his 2nd time slot

```
        <div class="row" >
      <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput [min]="startDate" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Meeting date" name="meetingDate" required>
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select placeholder="Pick Hour" name="meetingHour" required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let timeVal of meetingHours" [value]="timeVal.value">
              {{ timeVal.viewValue }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select placeholder="Min(s)" name="meetingMin" required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let timeVal of meetingMins" [value]="timeVal.value">
              {{ timeVal.viewValue }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select placeholder="AM/PM" name="meetingAMPM"  required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let timeVal of meetingAMPMs" [value]="timeVal.value">
              {{ timeVal.viewValue }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select placeholder="Pick right Timezone" name="meetingTz"  required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let timeVal of timezones" [value]="timeVal.value">
              {{ timeVal.display }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <!--<button class="add" (click)="add()" ><img src="assets/images/plus.png"></button>-->
      </div>
    </div>
```

Button

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 mb-3" id="addNew">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary addnew pull-right" (click)="add()" value="Add New">
      </div>

    </div>
```

By default the above row will be displayed. On a click of "Add new" the row should be displayed again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is.. ..
You can use angular ngfor directive to iterate rows.. you can push a row to the array with add button..

Example :

html:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let row of rows">
 {{row.name}}
</div>
```

typescript:

```
//row array
rows:any[] = [];

//add button event
    add(){
     rows.push({name:'this is a row'});
    }
```

you can use any kind of array to list rows..

More details...
https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor